# Eye replacement?

Tags: discussion

I am in Australia so April 1st comes sooner for me.  I am  using Netscape and today have found that the browser seems to have had an upgrade so that animations finally work.

I think that the site looks good, but it is hurting my eyes.  I couldn't find an answer on Alta Vista.

Does anyone know a good eye surgeon so I can get better eyes?

Comment: Well April 1st has come and gone, but I for one enjoyed the trip down nostalgia lane...the Internet and websites have come a long way since the 90's. I locked this (for lack of a better option) so as not to confuse others who may not have seen Stack Exchange's April Fools' Day prank this year.

Answer (score 1):

It took me over an hour to download Netscape Navigator on AOL. My 14.4 kpbs modem kept defaulting to 9.6, and my family kept picking up the line…

The site looks pretty cool, but what's all this JavaScript thing I keep hearing about - no way am I going to use that!  And where's the hit counter at? How am I supposed to know if it's a good site or not?

Try using Lycos, I was able to find at least 8 eye doctors in the United States after sorting through 10 pages of results. Did you know cats have reflective eyes to see better at night? Don't let them look at this page, it could blind them. See you on ICQ!